# How do you pass typedef'd blocks as params to a block that itself is a parameter to a method?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a method that takes one parameter. This paramter is a block.
This block itself takes two parameters, which are also blocks. They have
the characteristic of returning void and accepting one argument that
references an object.

For convenience let's typedef the blocks that are the parameters to the
other block.

```
typedef void (^MyParamBlock)(id);
```

Then, the method that takes a block looks something like

```
[self someMethod:^(MyParamBlock pBlock1, MyParamBlock pBlock2) {
  // . . .
}
```

How do you create MyParamBlocks to pass to the method? The following view controller code is an example. The MyParamBlocks pb1 and pb2 do not get passed to the call to someMethod.

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  PassingBlocksAsParamsToABlock

#import "ViewController.h"

typedef void (^MyParamBlock)(id);

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    MyParamBlock pb1 = ^(id obj) {
        NSLog(@"%@", obj);
    };

    MyParamBlock pb2 = ^(id obj) {
        NSLog(@"%@", obj);
    };

    [self someMethod:^(MyParamBlock pb1, MyParamBlock pb2) {
        NSString *str = @"strng";
        NSLog(@"%@", str);
        pb1(str);
        pb2(str);
    }];
}

- (void)someMethod:(void(^)(MyParamBlock, MyParamBlock))block
{
    NSLog(@"hallo");

    id pb1 = ^(id value) {
        // . .
    };

    id pb2 = ^(id anotherValue) {
        // . .
    };

    block(pb1, pb2);
}


@end
```

Comment: You have some variable shadowing going on in that block.

Comment: You don't pass pb1, pb2 to `someMethod`, it is the other way around: `someMethod` passes two blocks as arguments when calling the block that you passed to `someMethod`. - Perhaps you can show a more concrete example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MartinR - thanks that helps. I would accept that as an answer. Basically I misinterpreted some documentation I was reading and thought I had to roll my own blocks when I just needed to call the ones passed back to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(From my above comment:)* You don't pass `pb1`, `pb2` to `someMethod:`, it is exactly the other way around: `someMethod:` passes two blocks as arguments when calling the block that you passed to `someMethod:`.

Answer (score 3):

Your current version of someMethod takes a block that takes two `MyParamBlocks`.

```
- (void)someMethod:(void(^)(MyParamBlock, MyParamBlock))block
```

You probably want this...

```
- (void)someMethodWithFirstBlock:(MyParamBlock)firstBlock secondBlock:(MyParamBlock)secondBlock
```

Or maybe...

```
- (void)someMethodWithParameterBlocks:(NSArray *)parameterBlocks; //of MyParamBlocks
```